# Rails nested form Unpermitted parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

When i create or edit product, my merchant_product_detail will not be created or edit due to
**Unpermitted parameter: `merchant_id`**. But other like id and price are able to pass strong parameters, only merchant_id could not pass it. Kindly help me why my merchant_id is not permit in this case?

**`params` return in `binding.pry` mode**

```
"product"=>
      {"name"=>"fewrgvers",
       "description"=>"",
       "product_categories_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>""}},
       "merchant_product_details_attributes"=>
        {"0"=>{"merchant_id"=>["2"], "id"=>"", "price"=>"123"}}
    "
```

**`product_params` return**

```
    Unpermitted parameter: merchant_id
    => {"name"=>"fewrgvers",
     "description"=>"",
     "merchant_product_details_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"", "price"=>""}}
```

**product.rb**

```
has_many :merchant_product_details
accepts_nested_attributes_for :merchant_product_details, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['merchant_id'].blank? }
has_many :merchants, through: :merchant_product_details
```

**merchant.rb**

```
has_many :merchant_product_details
has_many :products, through: :merchant_product_details
accepts_nested_attributes_for :merchant_product_details
```

**merchant_product_detail.rb**

```
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :merchant
```

**product_controller.rb**

```
 def new
    @product = Product.new
    @product.merchant_product_details.build
end

def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
end

def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update_attributes(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
end


params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, 
      merchant_product_details_attributes: [:id, :merchant_id, :price]
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@product, :url => path, html: { class: "form-horizontal", role: "form" }) do |f| %>
<%= f.fields_for :merchant_product_details do |builder| %>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <%= builder.label :merchant_id, class: "col-md-2 control-label" %>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <%= builder.select :merchant_id, Merchant.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {include_hidden: false} ,prompt: "Select something", multiple: true, class: "select2" %>
        <%= builder.hidden_field :id %><br>
              <%= builder.label :price %>
        <%= builder.number_field :price %>
      </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `multiple: true` in the form field for `merchant_id`. This means that the param will be an array, as it could be multiple merchant ids.

If this is what you want then I would recommend changing the name to `merchant_ids` and allow an array like this:

```
params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, 
  merchant_product_details_attributes: [:id, :price, merchant_ids: []])
```

Having a look at your model relations I think you only want to have one id though, in which case it should be enough to remove the `multiple: true` in the select.

```
<%= builder.select :merchant_id, Merchant.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {include_hidden: false}, prompt: "Select something", class: "select2" %>
```